# Converting SQL query to Rails query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I could just use a `find_by_sql` to accomplish this, but I'd like to do it the Rails way if possible.

My SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT regions.id, max(updated_at) FROM demographics 
JOIN regions ON (regions.id = demographics.region_id) 
JOIN region_stats ON (region_stats.region_id = regions.id) 
WHERE region_stats.income_level = 1    
GROUP BY demographics.region_id;
```

Is there a way to convert this cleanly to Rails?

Comment: It's not clear what table the field `updated_at` belongs to, can you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested:

```
Demographic.joins(:region => [:region_stats]).select('demographics.region_id, max(demographics.updated_at) as `max_date`').where(:region_stats => {:income_level => 1}).group('demographics.region_id')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Demographic.find(:all,
  :conditions=>[
    "region_stats.income_level = ?",
    1
  ],
  :joins=>"as demographics JOIN regions ON (regions.id = demographics.region_id) JOIN region_stats ON (region_stats.region_id = regions.id)",
  :group=>"demographics.region_id",
  :select=>"regions.id, demographics.max(updated_at)"
)
```